# Android getApplicationContext() on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-context

I'm very new to Android development and the idea of context. So if it appears that I'm obviously doing the wrong thing, please explain what I should be doing instead.

I'm trying to pass my application context to a constructor (so that I can access my DB tables in that object) but I keep running into the following error:

> `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.Context
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getApplicationContext on a
>   null object reference`

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
public class FragmentShoppingList extends Fragment{

    MyApplication myApplication = new MyApplication();

    public FragmentShoppingList() {

    }

    SQLiteShoppingCartService sqLiteShoppingCartService = new SQLiteShoppingCartService(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
}
```

Why is `getActivity()` returning a null reference?

Comment: just go through fragment lifecycle you'll get it

Comment: instead writing getActivity() only will also work

Answer (score 0):

Fragment can exist independent of the `activity` it is hosted in. See [fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments). The code initializes your `sqLiteShoppingCartService` when the fragment instance is created. When the instance is created, the fragment is not a part of any activity. It later attaches to the activity.
Use **onActivityCreated** lifecycle method to initialize your `sqLiteShoppingCartService`.

Answer (score 0):

try with `getActivity()` Only.

Instead of `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called **onAttach(Context context)** in Android Fragment's lifecycle

`SQLiteShoppingCartService sqLiteShoppingCartService = new SQLiteShoppingCartService(getActivity().getApplicationContext());`

This above line is called when **FragmentShoppingList's** object is created. Context is given to a Fragment in this case **FragmentShoppingList's** object only when the fragment is attached to the window and that happens on **onAttach(Context context)** method.

```
MyApplication myApplication = new MyApplication();
```

I believed MyApplication extends from Application, if that is the case don't create like this. It is the entry point for every Android Application once you reference it in Android.Manifest file.